# Can I transfer my VS 2010 to my new virtual private server (VPS)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm now leasing my own server from 1and1.  Can I take the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate -- which I paid like 1100 bucks for -- and move it to the server?

Is it even necessary?  I don't know how ws_ftp will work ... I've never had my own server.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you use Visual Studio to develop on your local machine, then publish your web app and run the compiled code on IIS on your web server (ie on 1and1).

To publish your app, select the web project and click Build -> Publish. Then, FTP the files to your web server. You will need to configure IIS accordingly. There's loads of info out there for that. A few googles will sort you out.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, gwynhowell ... I appreciate it!